# Getting onReceive callback for chrome UDP socket on Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, google-chrome-app, windows-firewall

I am creating packaged app for chrome and using UDP socket to receive a broadcast message registering for [onReceive callback](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp#event-onReceive) for the socket created.

On Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 to be specific) I receive the callback as expected.

But on Windows (Windows 7 to be specific) I don't get the callback.

I guessed it is issue with firewall and opened the port I was using for the chrome browser as described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7)

Now everything works fine.

My question is , is this the only solution?
Users who install my app need to manually open the port as above or is there any alternatives available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've stumbled on the same issue, how did you work around this problem?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution.All I had to was to include an instruction in the app page on how to open the port for windows :)